# Can not find docker container

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose

I have asp core api project and i am using visual studio 2017 to run my project.
After i renamed the docker container that was previously created using visual studio using this command on command line,

```
docker rename CONTAINER NEW_NAME
```

I receive the following message when i try to run the project again in visual studio.

Thanks for the help

```
Can not find docker container with the name starting with 'previous_container_name'.
```

Comment: what system do you use? can you look which images are build? do you start docker-compose with docker-compose.yml and vsc? give us a bit more informations please

Comment: If you run it using VS "Docker" button then all the names are hardcoded and cannot be changed. Actually you cannot change even some lines inside Dockerfile and docker-compose.

Answer (score 36):

Delete the `.vs` folder in your solution directory (close the solution first), the Docker image name seems to be cached somewhere in there.

Comment: Chances are that you need to close Visual Studio as well because it holds a handle on the .vs folder.

Answer (score 17):

This error started happening to me when someone on the team unchecked the build checkbox for the docker-compose project. Make sure it is enabled in Build -> Configuration Manager

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, and it was caused because I started Docker after opening the project. VS does some things with Docker on opening of the project, and will fail if Docker is not started.

Lesson learned: make sure Docker is running before starting Visual Studio. If Docker is not started, then start Docker, close your solution, and re-open it.

VS will re-create the container as it opens the project.

Answer (score 3):

This happened for me because I stopped a container manually via the commandline, then Visual Studio got confused.

To get round the issue I simply added a single ' ' space character to docker-compose.yml and saved the file. This forced Visual Studio to restart the container and connect to it.

I'm sure starting/stopping Visual Studio would also have worked, but the whitespace change was nice and fast.

Answer (score 2):

I also have the similar problem. 
These steps always help me to solve the issues. 
 Solution 1:

```
    1- Close VS 
    2- delete obj folder of root solution folder.
    3- delete obj folder of all projects which are involved in docker-compose file.(example all APIs)
    4- Open VS 
    5- Remove the docker-compose project from solution and add it again.
     During the creation process, don't overwrite the old files with new ones, to prevent deletion of you current docker-compose.yml configuration.
```

Solution 2:

```
    On the first time of container creation, copy the creation command: 
    example: docker-compose  -f "[path]\docker-compose.yml" -f "[path]\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "[path]\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose17926074389345686639 --no-ansi up -d --no-build --force-recreate --remove-orphans

   any time there is an error just run this command manually.
```

if anybody could find a constant solution please also let us know.

Answer (score 0):

One more cause is using solution folders for your docker project and a version of Visual Studio 2017 less than 15.9, upgrading to 15.9+ fixed this for me, see [this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/314882/single-project-docker-experience-breaks-if-using-s.html).

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have tried all of those but solution is very simple in **V.S. 2019**

Before all there is a bugfix packet for visual studio 2017 even if you using 19 beta, for this on https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/
Download and install that pocket.

For automatically composing also you should add **Docker Compose Support** follow this link https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/standard/containerized-lifecycle-architecture/design-develop-containerized-apps/visual-studio-tools-for-docker

1-) Right click to targeted project root folder on solution explorer that contains Dockerfile and select add-> Docker Support it will ask you its always contains would you like to create new one? Click yes. It will create new **Dockerfile**.

You will see some changes in new **Dockerfile** like your project changes or nuget package changes affectness

2-) Right click the newly replaced **Dockerfile** and Build Image.
It will successfully build

3-) Choose debugger as Docker instead IIS Express vs. Even don't use other debugger while developing project if you do not need

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had both the "image" section and the "build" section in my docker-compose.yml. I just removed the build section because I wanted it to pull an image from the docker registry, and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

If your project uses Launch profiles to run, I fixed this with the following steps:

1. Open Manage Docker compose launch settings VS.
2. Select the Launch Profile you are currently using to run the application.
3. Check id the specific service is selected in the launch profile or not. All the services you intent to run should be part of the Launch profile.

[image: screenshot]